# Display phone numbers instead of contact name in recent calls

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, contacts

I restored my contacts from iCloud after restoring my iPhone 6 Plus and setting up as a new iPhone and then imported sim contacts. I am now having an issue when I get an incoming call; it shows the caller's name but when I go to recents it only shows the number!

Comment: Try force-quitting the phone app by double-tapping the home button and swiping up the phone app. Also do a force restart (hold home+sleep/wake for a few seconds until your phone reboots).

Answer (score -1):

Restarting both messaging and phone apps worked for me.